# AliasMatch inside <if? directory

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4

I'm trying to use `AliasMatch` with `<If>` directory in my server configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf/` but it tells me that `AliasMatch not allowed here`

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'localhost:8000'">
    AliasMatch   /here/(.*)        /there/$1
</If>
```

What I'm trying to do is executing AliasMatch based on a QUERY_PARAM (now you see HTTP_HOST but I was just trying it). Is it possible to do it in some way? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It likely does not work because If is a glorified Location/Directory section, which Alias didn't support (because it basically has a location parameter and a directory parameter)

But, what you describe is a pretty tried-and-true simple RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} + RewriteRule recipe.

Comment: Actually I almost solved in another way. I preferred to stick with AliasMatch so I wrote it outside the directive because it actually it doesn't make any sense to do it every time a condition is triggered. So what I put in the If is what I need to handle for each request.